# Plotting measurements over time in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot in R that shows post-surgical outcomes over time. I want to plot a certain data point at pre-op, 1 month post-op, 6 months post-op, etc. Here is an example dataframe:

```
dat <- data.frame(Preop=c(-2,0.5,-0.25,1.5), PO_1M=c(-1.5,0.2,-0.1,1.0), PO_6M=c(-1.2,0.1,-0.05,0.5), PO_1Y=c(-1.0,0.05,0,0.25))
dat
```

Ideally, the x axis will have markings for the time (preop, 1 month post-op, etc.), and the y axis will have the value at that time. The data should converge around y=0 coming from either the positive or negative direction, and I imagine a plot looking something like this:
[image]

My actual dataframe also has many missing values, so this would need to be accounted for somehow. I would appreciate if anyone could help approach this problem using either ggplot or base R plotting functions. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data should be restructured.  Use tidyr package to help make your columns into rows. Then use `ifelse` logic to convert your column names into the number of months.  I assigned pre-op to zero months.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat2<-dat %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(cols=Preop:PO_1Y)

dat2$nummonths<-ifelse(dat2$name=='Preop',0,
             ifelse(dat2$name=='PO_1M',1,
                    ifelse(dat2$name=='PO_6M',6,
                                  ifelse(dat2$name=='PO_1Y',12,NA))))



ggplot(dat2, aes(nummonths,value))+geom_point()+theme_dark()
```

Comment: nice first answer. The OP might not want the x axis continuous. any suggestion for them how to make sure the order stays as intended if they keep it as a categorical axis?

Comment: P.S. as an aside, staying in the tidyverse syntax, using `mutate(... = case_when ...)` slightly simplifies those nested if else statements